# Update/Set multiple column with set and select statement

Tags: sql-server, database

I have below trigger written which works perfectly fine for single column update (firstname), however we now need to update few extra columns (lastname, mobileNumber etc.)

```
CREATE TRIGGER apl.updateJaWithCandidateDataAfterInsert ON [APL].[tblJobApplications_v2]
AFTER INSERT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

UPDATE [APL].[tblJobApplications_v2]
SET FirstName = (
        SELECT FirstName
        FROM [USR].[tblUserDetails]
        WHERE inserted.CandidateId = [USR].[tblUserDetails].CandidateId
        )
FROM [APL].[tblJobApplications_v2]
INNER JOIN Inserted ON [APL].[tblJobApplications_v2].CandidateId = Inserted.CandidateId
GO
```

Tried few options but couldnt make those work.Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may required one more inner join for `[USR].[tblUserDetails]`

```
UPDATE [APL].[tblJobApplications_v2]
SET FirstName = [USR].[tblUserDetails].FirstName,
    LastName  = [USR].[tblUserDetails].LastName
FROM [APL].[tblJobApplications_v2]
INNER JOIN Inserted ON [APL].[tblJobApplications_v2].CandidateId = Inserted.CandidateId
INNER JOIN [USR].[tblUserDetails] ON inserted.CandidateId = [USR].[tblUserDetails].CandidateId
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, thanks. Please edit and remove comma after the LastName, else all good :)

Comment: Thanks, That was just typo